# how to create git branch in remote repository without checking out using jgit

Tags: git, branch, git-remote, jgit, git-checkout

Can we create a remote branch in git using jgit without checking out. For example I want to create a branch named *foo* from branch named *bar* in my remote repository without checking out branch *bar* locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have at least one branch '`bar`' in your local repo in order to push it under a different name '`foo`'.
But you don't have to checkout that local branch '`bar`' first.

See this [JGit push test example](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/f3fc3797579ac0bf55648bad560e7daa5e6df9b5/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java#L100):

```java
RefSpec spec = new RefSpec("refs/heads/bar:refs/heads/foo");
git1.push().setRemote("test").setRefSpecs(spec).call();
```

Comment: To do as you mentioned I have to clone the repository. What I want to do is create a branch remotely without cloning it locally. does jgit provide that facility?

Comment: @Buddy no, jgit won't provide that feature. Nor will git. Or any other library (libgit2, ...). What you describe would be only possible if you have access to the remote server, adding a new branch directly in the bare repo. You can clone only one branch though.

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot create remote branch without cloning**. 
But **you can create remote branch without checking-out**.

To be specific, you can clone just '.git' directory(not working directory) with "setNoCheckout(true)," and then create remote branch and push.

Let's see my example:

```
// clone repository. Like to 'git clone -n repository'
Git.cloneRepository().setURI(projectURL).setDirectory(repositoryFile)
  .setCredentialsProvider(credentials).setCloneAllBranches(true).setNoCheckout(true)
  .call();

// create branch locally
git.branchCreate().setName(targetBranch).setForce(true)
  .setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK).setStartPoint(startPoint)
  .call();

// push created branch to remote repository
// This matches to 'git push targetBranch:targetBranch'
RefSpec refSpec = new RefSpec().setSourceDestination(targetBranch, targetBranch);   
git.push().setRefSpecs(refSpec).setCredentialsProvider(credentials).call();
```

I use jgit version 3.3.0.201403021825-r. And this works fine for me.

Comment: Interesting addition to my answer, skipping the checkout step can be interesting. +1

Comment: I'm trying to use your code and I get a "Ref HEAD cannot be resolved"  (my branch name is master)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a remote branch using the rest api curl command

/rest/branch-utils/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/branches

[Rest api and curl command](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/5.0.1/bitbucket-branch-rest.html)